# Hide a Div only if its already shown

Tags: jquery

I need to hide the popup when once if the user click on anywhere else on the page popupbox:visible doesn't works for me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                            $(".popupbox").hide();
                        });
                         $(".ribbon").click(function() {
                            $(".popupbox").toggle();
                        })
                      $(".popupbox img").click(function() {
                            $(".popupbox").hide();
                        })

                      $("body").click(function() {
                            $(".popupbox:visible").hide();

                        })
```

Comment: Why not just use `$('.popupbox').hide()`? If it's not visible, nothing will happen

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body"):not('.popupbox, .popupbox *').click(function() {
    $(".popupbox:visible").hide();
})
```

Comment: do you mean like that

 $(document).ready(function() {
                             $(".popupbox").hide();
                            });
                             $(".ribbon").click(function() {
                             $(".popupbox").toggle();
                            })
               $(".popupbox img").click(function() {
                             $(".popupbox").hide();
                            })
       $("body"):not('.popupbox, .popupbox *').click(function() {
        $(".popupbox:visible").hide();
       })

Comment: remove all clicks and put this one. If doesn't work then revert back to me

Comment: Please specify clearly? what do you want and what current code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(".popupbox").css("display", "none");` instead of `$(".popupbox:visible").hide();`

Comment: under which like ?